# Click and hold element in selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How to set time holding element when clicks on an element in selenium?

```
buider.clickAndHold(elmt).moveToElement(listassign).release().build().perform();
```

Comment: what are u trying to achieve. drag and drop scenario?

Comment: Overload the clickAndHold method and add a wait time. It's not possible with the default methods to wait with ActionBuilder.

Comment: I want hold an element about sometime then drop this element.. can you help me?

Comment: FMD how to overload the clickAndHold method/